# Why always store shortnames for emojis?

Tags: database, web-applications, unicode, emoji

On [EmojiOne's Github page](https://github.com/Ranks/emojione), they say:

> When storing user inputted text in your database, [...] you should always make sure you are storing text containing only :shortnames: and not Unicode emoji characters [...].

Why is it *always* a bad idea ? If my server language, my database, and the browsers versions supported by my web app can all handle them without difficulty, where is the problem?

Comment: Sounds very opinion based to me. It reduces headaches about encoding compatibility, but then again, if you're handling your encodings incorrectly, you have bigger problems to begin with.

Comment: Have you asked the project's authors? It sounds like very poor advice. There's noting special or unusual about emoji characters (vs. other Unicode characters).

Answer (score 1):

After a few days of reading on emoji and looking at emojione, my conclusion -- I would not store shortcodes (what emojione called shortnames) in your storage mechanism/db. As suggested by a comment in your question, simply store the character (the emoji: ) itself in your database.

For those just starting to learn what emoji are, they are simply another character in the unicode standard. Letters, numbers, exclamation points, Japanese characters, etc etc are all characters part of the unicode standard. There's nothing special about emoji, you can simply think of them like any other unicode character. All modern browsers will render them correctly.

The primary reason I would not store shortcodes is simplicity. By storing the actual unicode character , you don't have to do any type of conversion when displaying the character to a user. If you were to store the shortcode, in this case that's `:grinning:`, you'll have to do some sort of conversion to correctly display a grinning face to the user.

Emojione's library has the ability to convert either the unicode itself or shortcodes to their images. Given that, just store unicode and use emojione's library to convert them before displaying to the user. If you want to stop using emojione in the future and use the standard browser implementation of emoji, you'll have no extra work to do.